# Tiles in tags possible?

Tags: spring-roo, tiles, tiles2, apache-tiles

I'am using spring roo v.1.2.3. Roo generated `*.tagx`-s, `*.jspx`-s and `views.xml`-s that is good.

But can I put those `*.jspx` page fragments in `*.tagx`-s. 
For example there is a tag `table.tagx` and I want to insert after each row a corresponding `update.jspx`. Is it possible to modify tag or other thing to make it work or I should find another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the tag files, although keep in mind those tag files generated by Roo will be reused.  Think of Roo as a boiler-plate generator, in which you can modify anything it produces.